# Is there an Open Source MTP (Media Tranfer Protocol) Responder Implementation for BeagleBone devices

Tags: mtp

I am looking for an Open Source MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) responder implementation for BeagleBone boards.  Alternatively, an embedded Linux implementation that includes an MTP responder implementation.

Note, this is not the same as the MTP initiator as found with gmtp and similar.

Answer (score 2):

take a look here:

from buteo project

1)  https://git.merproject.org/mer-core/buteo-mtp

from ubuntu

2) http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~phablet-team/mtp/trunk/files

or android

3)https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/jni/

i have already got ubuntu and buteo-version both running on BBB.

Answer (score 2):

Another MTP responder have been developed recently :

https://github.com/viveris/uMTP-Responder

Implemented in C, in user space and use the GadgetFs layer.

This wasn't tested yet on BeagleBone but this shouldn't be a problem. You just have to change the gadgetFS settings in the config file.

More details on the github project page.